# Подтверждение записи данных в mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Как можно реализовать проверку того что данные записались в базу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этой цели в MongoDB специально введено понятние [**Write Concern**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/). Выдержка из документации:

> ### write concern
>
> Specifies whether a write operation
> has succeeded. Write concern allows
> your application to detect insertion
> errors or unavailable [`mongod`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod)
> instances. For [replica sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-replica-set), you
> can configure write concern to confirm
> replication to a specified number of
> members. See [Write Concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/).

***Дословно:***
Указывает, успешно ли выполнилась операция записи. "Write concern" позволяет вашим приложениям выявлять ошибки вставки или недоступности mongod. Для replica-set вы можете задать write concern, чтобы подтверждать репликацию в заданное число реплик.

Существует определенный набор значений для этого параметра:

- ***Unacknowledged***
- ***Acknowledged*** (by default)
- ***Journaled***
- ***Replica Acknowledged***

По умолчанию драйвером используется ***Acknowledged*** уровень - `mongod` в этом случае будет сообщать клиенту о результатах записи. Т.е. клиент может отловить сетевые ошибки , получить сообщение `duplicate key` или другую ошибку. (Всё расписано в документации).

Значение write concern'а в драйвере [можно поменять в классе MongoClient](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/).